# how to Prevent loading .NET exe/dll if not signed with a trusted certificate?

Tags: .net, security, certificate, digital-signature

One of our customer has the requirement to prevent loading exe/dll (and also loading assembly within IIS) if they are not signed with a trusted certificate.

I did not find clear answer to this question...

Can someone provide me some hints on this?

Thanks a lot,
José

Comment: Take a look at software restriction policies, or applocker if its applicable - or even Family Safety may be useful